# Installing an appx file from visual studio generated packages fails

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2012, appx

I have developed a cordova app with ionic and packaged it using visual studio

After generating a `.appx file` and transfering it to my windows 10 tablet

```
1,OPENED properties
2 digital signatures
3 details
4 view certificate
5 install certificate
```

Still even ater the above process am getting an error

```
Either you need a new certificate for this package or a new app 
       from trusted package with trusted certificate
A certificate chain processed but terminated in a root certificate
 which is not trusted(0*800B0109)
```

I have folowed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812471/installing-appx-without-trusted-certificate) it fails to work.

What could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you are importing the certificate under **Trusted Root Certification Authorities** section of the Local Machine certificates store. Also the Sideloading feature should be enabled. The [Sideload LOB apps in Windows 10](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/sideload-apps-in-windows-10) article should help.