# Issue while installing appx bundle on another windows 10 PC

Tags: uwp, windows-10, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-universal, appx

I have created app package and tried to run it on my pc (windows 10) by clicking it's appxbundle. It is running. But when copied the same appxbundle on another windows 10 PC it shows `"Either you need a new certificate installed for this app package, or you need a new app package with trusted certificates. Your system administrator or the app developer can help. A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which isn’t trusted (0x800B0109)."` How to solve it?

What I did to create appx is explaining here.

First in Manifest file > under packaging > View full certifcate > Install Certificate > Local Machine > certifcate store selected as 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' > Ok >Which shows Import was successful.

And then selected store > Create App Packages. Selected 'No' in the first dialog asking if you want to build packages to upload to the Windows Store.Checked the release mode. App package is also created.

How can I create this package without the issue of certificate? I dont want to publish it in store. Just need to run the appxbundle on all windows devices

Comment: This error means the certificate you used to sign the appx package is not trusted on that other PC. Find the .cer file in the appx output folder, and copy it to that PC and right click to install that .cer. Then you should be able to install the appx without cert issue.

Comment: See also this answer. [Installing .appx without trusted certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24372483/815938)