# Install universal windows App on another Windows 10 for testing

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, windows-10, certificate, win-universal-app

I've a problem. I wanted mode to install a release of universal windows app.
When i copy the AppPackeges on the remote computer, this doesn't install beaces return this error:

> Either you need a new certificate installed for this app package, or
>   you need a new app package with trusted certificates. Your system
>   administrator or the app developer can help. A certificate chain
>   processed, but terminated in a root certificate which isn't trusted
>   (0x800B0109)

I follow this tips: [Installing .appx without trusted certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812471/installing-appx-without-trusted-certificate)

But didn't work for me...i'm continually receive the error on the quote.
There is another mode to run a universa windows app on the another windows 10 for testing.
I used a certificate created from visual studio 2017.

Then i've set windows 10 on developer mode.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just trying to click on the appx or using the PowerShell script that VS provides?  The PowerShell script should install the certificate if its missing.

Comment: How to do to running installation by power shell ?

Comment: @MichaelHawker-MSFT i've tryed using power shell but doesn't work.

Comment: double click on the certificate to install it on the 2nd PC, now install the appx via double click

Comment: I've installed the certificate. I've solved like this: i've added the certificate on the certificate windows folder manually. Now Works.

Comment: Does your test  machine has multiple accounts?