# What's the easiest way to setup UWP program on a offline computer?

Tags: uwp

It is the first time I develop UWP program, and now I have to setup it to an offline computer of the factory(Let me give the computer a name:C). I was under the illusion that setup a UWP program is as easy as the win32 program, but it turns out to be not.

I used the way as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-appinstallerfile-vs said. But after I ran the appxbundle, it said that I need to setup a certificate for this app. I don't know what is the meaning and how to find a certificate for my app?

Finally, I found a stupid way that setup visual studio on C as first. Then copies the source solution to a removable disk. After doing this, open the source solution and runs on the local machine. With this, visual studio will automatically setup the UWP program to the computer. At last, remove the removable disk so that no one can find the source project and the program is OK now.

Whereas, although this stupid way works, it is troublesome if you need to update the program. So I am finding an easiest way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: this might help : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ec0d9298-34da-43f0-a192-b636097246b4/appxappxbundle-install-issue-certificate-problem?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: The certificate file you are looking for is in the same folder as the appbundle, with a .cer extension. Just double click it and follow the wizard to install it (on computer C). After that, you can run the appxbundle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-upload-file):

In Solution Explorer, open the solution for your UWP app project.

1. Right-click the project and choose Store->Create App Packages. If this option is disabled or does not appear at all, check that the project is a Universal Windows project.
2. The Create App Packages wizard appears. Select **I want to create package for sideloading**, then click next.
3. In the next step, change any information you need to change and click create after completing.

4.this will generate a folder called *AppPackages* with an  appxbundle installer.

You will be able to distribute your app this time to an offline computer. Just take the folder that was created. On that offline computer, open the installer, and you know the rest.

**Edit:**
Seems that I totally missed your point.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812471/installing-appx-without-trusted-certificate), I think, that will solve your problem.