# ADFS installation failed with SSL certificate

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-web-app-service, adfs, ws-federation

when configured adfs with windows 2016, i got the error `the certificate specified doesn't meet the requirement`

I did install and configure ADFS on windows server 2016 Datacentor,  when the last step  i got the following error, as the suggestion from  https://ulyssesneves.com/2021/05/13/ad-fs-troubleshooting-error-the-certificate-specified-does-not-meet-all-the-requirements-of-an-ssl-certificate/?cn-reloaded=1 , i tried following command, however it doesn't work.

could someone suggest the solutions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bv9M.jpg)

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-WebApplicationProxySslCertificate -Thumbprint "BC8374123E87A14C03FFF1EB7963631B76AE690C"
Set-WebApplicationProxySslCertificate : The term 'Set-WebApplicationProxySslCertificate' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WebApplicationProxySslCertificate -Thumbprint "BC8374123E87A14C03 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-WebApplicationProxySslCertificate:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException



PS C:\Windows\system32> Set-AdfsSslCertificate -Thumbprint BC8374123E87A14C03FFF1EB7963631B76AE690C
Set-AdfsSslCertificate : The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the
Faulted state.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-AdfsSslCertificate -Thumbprint BC8374123E87A14C03FFF1EB7963631B76 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-AdfsSslCertificate], CommunicationObjectFaultedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException,Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management.Commands.SetSslCertificateComma
   nd
```

Comment: The cmdlet Set-WebApplicationProxySslCertificate is not installed on machine or is not in a path for environmental variable PSMODULEPATH.  In PS a cmdlet is first located in current folder and if not found then uses PSMODULEPATH to locate cmdlet.

Comment: Installation error is due to a certificate not being signed.  Signing just means a CRC is added to certificate so nobody tampers with the certificate.  It is like signing a PDF document.  See following for possible solutions : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812471/installing-appx-without-trusted-certificate?force_isolation=true